# How to Enable assert in java

Tags: java, assert

i am using eclipse and getting an error  assertArrayEquals(expectedPos, sent.getPosTags().toArray()); is not Defined? i have imported

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

idont know how to fix it?

```
    ArrayList<Range> gotRanges = new ArrayList<Range>();
    Iterables.addAll(gotRanges, sent.getNpChunkRanges());

    assertEquals(expectedLength, sent.getLength());
```

- **
- assertArrayEquals(expectedPos, sent.getPosTags().toArray());

  1. assertArrayEquals(expectedToks, sent.getTokens().toArray());

**
        assertEquals(expectedRanges, gotRanges);

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting of your code but I can't understand it. what to the `**` mean?

Comment: getting an error at eclipse at compile time

Comment: ...and what does the error message say?

Comment: Did You added dependencies for TestNG/JUnit?

Comment: @Disco error is The method assertArrayEquals(String[], Object[]) is undefined for the type

Comment: @Disco i am alos getting at  double[] expectedJane = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
  double[] gotJane = StringFeatures.featureSet.featurizeToDouble("jane");
  assertArrayEquals(expectedJane, gotJane, 0.001);

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which of your assertArrayEquals is at fault, but for at least one you are passing in, String[] as the first parameter and Object[] as the second parameter. If you look at the JavaDoc for the Assert class http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html there is no method that takes those two parameters.

Check the types of the variables you are passing in (we can't do that as you haven't included all the definition in your code)

*Also* if one is an array of Objects and one an array of Strings, that's a clue they are not equal:-)

For the second bit of code you mention

```
double[] expectedJane = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
double[] gotJane = StringFeatures.featureSet.featurizeToDouble("jane");       
assertArrayEquals(expectedJane, gotJane, 0.001);
```

you are calling a method assertArrayEquals(double[], double[], double). Have a look at the javadoc, does that method exist?

Answer (score 0):

You message is not clear.

It seems that you are not using the right types for the [assertEquals](http://www.cs.laurentian.ca/badams/c2006/junit-docs/junit/framework/Assert.html) method.

Comment: Error at assertArrayEquals(expectedJane, gotJane, 0.001); double[]=expectedjane,gotjane & double=0.0001.